# Loop through object of objects

Tags: javascript

So I have the following function vanilla JS code:

```
function get_menu(menu_id) {
    wp.api.loadPromise.done(function() {
        const menus = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
            url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/menus/' + menu_id,
        });
        const Menus = new menus();
        Menus.fetch().then(
            posts => {
            let post_list = posts.items;
            console.log(post_list);
        });
    });
}
get_menu(4);
```

This gives me a object of objects as shown below:
[image]

What is the best way to loop through these objects and render HTML within? So let's say I want to loop through each object and grab the `post_title` and output HTML `<div> + post_title + </div>`.

All help would be appreciated!

Update:

Need to render this in a loop:

```
<div class="column is-one-third is-flex py-0">
    <a href=" ***url*** " class="dropdown-item px-2 is-flex is-align-items-center">
        <figure class="image is-32x32 is-flex">
            <img src=" ***image*** + ***post_title*** '.svg'; ?>">
        </figure>
        <span class="pl-2"><?= ***post_title*** ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The result shown in the console is actually an array of objects. As such, you can just walk through the array, doing as you please with the info each element contains. Notice that the 5th and last characters of the first line are `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the array and create a dom tree

```
function get_menu(menu_id) {
  wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
    const menus = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
      url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/menus/' + menu_id,
    });
    const Menus = new menus();
    Menus
      .fetch()
      .then(posts => {
        let post_list = posts.items;
        // Map through response data and turn objects into elements
        const postElements = post_list.map(createDomTree)
        // spread all elements from array into arguments for the append method
        document.body.append(...postElements)
      });
  });
}

function createDomTree(post) {
  // I'm not sure if these values are available in the response data, but can be replaced
  const { post_url, post_title, post_image } = post
  const container = document.createElement('div')
  container.className = 'column is-one-third is-flex py-0'
  const anchor = document.createElement('a')
  anchor.href = post_url
  anchor.className = 'dropdown-item px-2 is-flex is-align-items-center'
  const figure = document.createElement('figure')
  figure.className = 'image is-32x32 is-flex'
  const img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = `${post_image}${post_title}.svg`
  const span = document.createElement('span')
  span.className = 'pl-2'
  span.textContent = post_title
  figure.appendChild(img)
  anchor.append(figure, span)
  container.appendChild(anchor)
  return container
}

get_menu(4);
```

Comment: Thanks @Uzair, this outputs well! So would I have to call a return or could I just call `get_menu(4)` and the divs will render automatically? Also, let's say I want more than just the post_title and a large HTML body, would I keep appending or how do I construct a big DOM Tree?

Comment: That is exactly correct, if you can edit your post with the exact html structure I can give you a better hand at understanding.

Comment: thanks so much! Updating now, give me on second please.

Comment: Hey Uzair, I updated the full HTML in the post at the bottom, I added the *** indicators which will be the object fields.

Comment: @DevSem updated the code, alot of it isn't explained very well but I can provide some links to documentation once I have a moment.

Comment: Thanks so much @Uzair, I would love some documentation, is it better to create a DOM Tree or have a `HTMLrender = "<div><p><br> etc... "` element all together?

Comment: From my experience, targetting innerHTML directly is a bad practice due to the possiblity of cross site scripting attacks.  But of course the choice is yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227511/discussion-between-devsem-and-uzair-ashraf).